# Can I change the default admin for wordpress pages?

Tags: wordpress

I know I can modify what default data entry areas show up when I make a custom post type, but is there a way to modify the default "pages" data entry -- for example, say I'd like to only provide the title and main text boxes.

For a custom post type, I'd use `'supports' => array('title, 'editor')` but I'm unsure as to how to apply this type of change to the "pages" interface.

Hope I'm asking this clearly, as I'm a bit new to WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to edit core code. The default post types are registered in `wp-includes/post.php` in a function called `create_initial_post_types`, kick it from there.

Comment: Please anyone who comes across this... Don't ever edit the WP core. This can be done with a plugin as we have by using the mu-plugins directory and putting a plugin there that will add CSS and JS to the admin head section so you can manipulate whatever you want.

It's a little hacky but you're hacking it naturally anyways. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

Drop this into your theme's functions.php file.

Comment/Uncomment what you need — it lets you remove items independently for posts and pages.

(I haven't tested it on an install that uses custom post types, but I'm assuming it will play nice.)

```
function unused_meta_boxes() {

    //remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv','post','normal'); // Comment Status
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv','page','normal'); // Comment Status

    //remove_meta_box('postexcerpt','post','normal'); // Excerpt
    remove_meta_box('postexcerpt','page','normal'); // Excerpt

    //remove_meta_box('authordiv','post','normal'); // Author
    remove_meta_box('authordiv','page','normal'); // Author

    //remove_meta_box('commentsdiv','post','normal'); // Comments
    remove_meta_box('commentsdiv','page','normal'); // Comments

    //remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv','post','normal'); // Trackbacks
    remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv','page','normal'); // Trackbacks

    //remove_meta_box('postcustom','post','normal'); // Custom Fields
    remove_meta_box('postcustom','page','normal'); // Custom Fields

    //remove_meta_box('slugdiv','post','normal'); // Slug
    remove_meta_box('slugdiv','page','normal'); // Slug

    //remove_meta_box('revisionsdiv','post','normal'); // Revisions
    remove_meta_box('revisionsdiv','page','normal'); // Revisions

    //remove_meta_box('postimagediv','post','side'); // Featured Image
    remove_meta_box('postimagediv','page','side'); // Featured Image

    //remove_meta_box('categorydiv','post','side'); // Categories

    //remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag','post','side'); // Tags

    remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv','page','side'); // Page Parent etc.
}
add_action('admin_head', 'unused_meta_boxes');
```

—

This is a **FAR** better method than hacking core files.

Comment: Quick note: removing the slug meta box can stop the edit permalink from working properly.